# Put div on top of Master Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am using master slider in (https://wordpress.org/plugins/master-slider/) and it works great.  However I need to add a div on top of it to display something so I have used the below but it still sits behind no matter what number is inside the z-index.

```
#on-top {
    margin-top:-50px;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

Comment: can u add some code! or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) of the same!

Answer (score 0):

You have to `position` an element in order to use `z-index` : `position:absolute;` or `position:relative;`

Answer (score 0):

```
#on-top {
    margin-top:-50px;
    z-index:9999;
    position:relative;
}
```

z-index will not work for static elements.So it should be relative, absolute or fixed positioned element.